# How to know the sort type when querying the list of files in a folder using Directory.GetFiles?

Tags: c#

I'm querying a folder using Directory.GetFiles() to get all *txt files and I'd like to get the first file in the list.  (I already know how to implement this)

However, I'd like the list to be sorted by having the newest date modified from the top so I'll get the most newest file first.

Any idea how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use OrderBy with the CreationTime property.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\");
FileSystemInfo[] files = di.GetFileSystemInfos("*.txt");
var orderedFiles = files.OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime);
```

For example, this code is getting all files In C, and sorting list by Creation time.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime.aspx) you can read more about that.

Comment: Thanks Farhad..if I only want txt files when getting all files, I just need to do di.GetFileSystemInfos("*.txt")?

Comment: @Mikk I think that yes. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var output = allFiles.OrderBy(item=> new FileInfo(item).CreationTime);
```

Comment: Can't you infer this from context? this is not hard.

Comment: If I explained this for you, there will be an upvote? I don't care, :)